# Can you run a callout to the tooling API as non-admin user without giving them "Modify All Permissions"?

Tags: tooling-api

Right now I have a button that uses the tooling api to query information for custom object and field for a URL Redirect. However when I use as a non-admin user, I get a type conversion error and when I look into the logs I see "sObject type 'CustomObject' is not supported." I understand giving the user "Modify All Data" fixes this but I cannot give them that permission because it will affect other functionality I'm working on that requires objects be set to private. Is there a way to make a callout to the tooling api as admin through another user?

Answer (score 1):

No. The Tooling API is an administrative API, giving the ability to create, modify, and delete metadata elements, things a Developer [Persona](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/ux-personas-for-salesforce/units/get_started_with_personas) would have need to do. Instead, you want to use the [SOAP describeSObjects()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects.htm) or [REST SObject Describe](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_describe.htm) APIs to get the describe information for the field. These APIs are meant for general-purpose use, and provide read-only access to describe information.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, unfortunately using describeSObjects does not help since I need the IDs that are found in the setup page in salesforce which are only available in the Tooling API.